# Find column in table SQL

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to search for a column name while on the Edit/Select Top 200 rows view in MSSQL?

Something like, press CTRL+F type the name of the columns and see where that column is located instead of manually looking for it.

Comment: I don't follow, what's wrong with `Ctrl`+`f`?

Comment: Are you looking for a column name or a value stored in a row for a specific column (or set of columns or in any column)? It is unusual to struggle with column names.

Comment: @Larnu There is no CTRL+F for searching the columns name while on edit view, and on select view u can only see where it is from the list not on the table itself.

Comment: @SMor looking for the column name, not the value. For instance i have a table with 50+ columns and I want to know, while on edit top rows view, where that column is located, as of now i can only do it by moving the bar until I find it.

Comment: Ahh, then the real solution is stop using the editor, @FranciscoSouza . Use a proper `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I just use the editor to view the table and see the changes that were made while running my code, I don't directly edit it from the editor.
I wanted a way to be easier to locate a column with creating a statement to filter it, only using the software interface.